# Search with Relationship - Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, model, relationship, laravel-5.3

Im making a search functionality where users can type in a name. This is the query im doing:

```
   public function api(Request $request)
    {
        $query = request()->get('query');

        $results = Listing::searchAndCache($query);

        return $results;
    }
```

Which hits this:

```
 public static function searchAndCache($query)
    {
        return self::where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')->where('live',true)->paginate(15);
    }
```

I also need to search 'location' along with this query, the problem is its in a diffrent table. The models name is Location. My question is how would I attach the model Location to this query?

So ideally, I would want to do this for the query:

```
 public static function searchAndCache($query)
    {
        return self::where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')->where('region','like','%'.$query.'%')->where('live',true)->paginate(15);
    }
```

Comment: By the way, in your `$query`, it's not `request()->get('query);`, it should be this: `$request->get('query);`

Comment: no, I could use it this way.

Comment: I know you can, but you are instantiating the Request, so why not use it? just saying.

Comment: Try this: you could add a third field in your pivot table, that will be a foreign key to the field in your other table, that way you could possibly access it in a convenient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For search you can use [searchable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout) trait. so you can do this :

```
Listing::where('live',true)->search($query)->paginate(15);
```

if there is a relation between Listing And Location, you can use Laravel realations to do something like this

```
Listing::where('live',true)
         ->search($query)
         ->location
         ->search($query2)
         ->paginate(15);
```